# Is it safe to reference the accumulator during a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, coffeescript, accumulator

Is there a correct way to reference the output of an `for` loop in CoffeeScript. It seems that using the internal variable `_results` works some of the time, but it does work in some situations (shown below). Is there a "correct" way to reference the accumulator that is stable?

Works

```
Array::unique = ->
  value for value in this when not (value in _results)
```

Doesn't work (renames iterator to `_results2`)

```
Array::unique = ->
  _results = null
  value for value in this when not (value in _results)
```

Also doesn't work (renames iterator to `_results2`)

```
Array::unique = ->
  value for value in (value for value in this) when not (value in _results)
```

Comment: You should not, under any circumstances, be able to access the accumulator.  If you think you need to, you are doing something wrong.  The name of the accumulator can change without warning, so don't rely on it.  I reported your first example as a bug on github (https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1637).

Comment: @Aaron That was my assumption. I was surprised that my first example worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accumulator is an implementation detail. You're not meant to interact with it. That's why it renames the variable if you're already using the name. It sounds like you want the reduce() function (Firefox has it built in and most of the popular libraries include support for it).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to interact with generated variables like `_results` directly from CoffeeScript. You could, however, do so with escaped JavaScript (which the compiler simply ignores):

```
Array::unique = ->
  value for value in this when not (`value in _results`)
```

compiles to

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  var value, _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = this.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    value = this[_i];
    if (!value in _results) {
      _results.push(value);
    }
  }
  return _results;
};
```

Stylistically, though, I think it'd be preferable to code your list comprehension in pure CoffeeScript. It's just 3 lines:

```
Array::unique = ->
  results = []
  results.push value for value in this when value not in results
  results
```

As to your implementation of the `unique` function (and I realize this is a bit of an aside), you should be aware that it's not going to scale well for large `N`, since it has to iterate through increasingly large arrays (except in special cases where the runtime's `indexOf` has better than O(N) efficiency). It's possible to handle large `N` relatively efficiently using a hash, though; see my proposed implementation of Underscore.js' _.uniq [here](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/156#issuecomment-1018283).

Comment: I was only using `Array::unique` as an example for my question. I don't care to much to the efficiency, but thanks for pointing me towards Underscore :)

Comment: Also I don't think your second suggested coffeescript example works.